# Тегу Select установить значение с ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Есть элемент select в котором 3 option. На страницу приходит **true** или **false** с помощью **ViewBag**. Если пришло **true**, то в **select** устанавливаем значение "Да", если **false**, то устанавливается "Нет". В инете ничего не смог найти. Помогите пожалуйста :)

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option>Не выбрано</option>
    <option value="true">Да</option>
    <option value="false">Нет</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А если добавить внутрь option: `@(myValue ? "selected" : "")`? Не сработает?

Comment: Андрей NOP это как вообще?

Comment: `<option value="true" @(myValue ? "selected" : "")>Да</option>` `<option value="false" @(!myValue ? "selected" : "")>Нет</option>`

Comment: Андрей NOP так я получаю ошибку "Вспомогательный тег "опция" не должен содержать C# в области объявления атрибутов элемента." Оригинал "The tag helper 'option' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area."

Comment: А если так: `<option value="true" selected="@(myValue)">Да</option>`? Либо вообще формируйте коллекцию `SelectListItem` во ViewBag и указывайте ее в `asp-items` тега `select`

Comment: @aepot , ты случайно не знаешь как это сделать?

Comment: Так он вас не услышит :)

Comment: Андрей NOP , почему?)

Comment: Ну потому что нельзя просто так взять и обратиться к случайному пользователю. Уведомление ему придет, только в случае, если он как-то участвовал в топике

Comment: ааа, не знал)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option>Не выбрано</option>
    @{
        if (ViewBag.Value)
        {
            <option value="true" selected>Да</option>
            <option value="false">Нет</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="true">Да</option>
            <option value="false" selected>Нет</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Так да работает) Спасибо